# WordPress custom function not passing Global Variables to other functions

Tags: php, wordpress, function, global-variables, global

I'm trying to pass Custom CSS in global variable to use it in another function then to pass it to `wp_enqueue_scripts` via `wp_add_inline_style` but the global variable whenever I use it as global it doesn't return anything only if i use `add_action('wp_footer', 'my_function')` below i'll show you my code and functions

I've tried many methods but still the same problem!

I use `cru_generate_custom_style` in many files to generate custom css for custom elements and based on **WordPress** you can’t run `wp_add_inline_style` anywhere else except `wp_enqueue_scripts` this is to eliminate errors on **W3C** and add inline style to `wp_head`

```
global $cru_bottom_styles;
$cru_bottom_styles = array();

function cru_generate_custom_style( $selector = '', $props = '', $media = '', $footer = true ) {
  global $cru_bottom_styles;

  $css = '';

    // Selector Start
    $css .= $selector . ' {' . PHP_EOL;

      // Selector Properties
    $css .= str_replace( ';', ';' . PHP_EOL, $props );

    $css .= PHP_EOL . '}';
    // Selector End

    // Media Wrap
    if ( trim( $media ) ) {
      $css = "@media {$media} { {$css} }";
    }


  if ( ! $footer || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    echo "<style>{$css}</style>";
    return;
  }

  $cru_bottom_styles[] = $css;
}

function cru_parse_header_styles() {
    global $cru_bottom_styles;
    print_r($cru_bottom_styles);

    wp_add_inline_style( 'main', implode( PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $cru_bottom_styles ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cru_parse_header_styles' );
```

Comment: I dont see where are you calling the "cru_generate_custom_style" function  in the code you've shared. based on that code alone, it'll never run.

Comment: also "wp_enqueue_scripts" is meant for enqueuing js files (and maybe css files), not for running php functions. you shoud try hooking it to "init" or a different hook.

Comment: @UriChachick use "cru_generate_custom_style" in many files to generate custom css for custom elements and based on wordpress you can’t run "wp_add_inline_style" anywhere else except "wp_enqueue_scripts" this is to eliminate errors on W3C and add inline style to "wp_head"

Comment: ok, are those files/functions from which you are calling "cru_generate_custom_style", hooked to a hook that runs before "wp_enqueue_scripts"?

Comment: @UriChachick they are in the post content as I told you I declared the global variable and add to array every selector with its properties in the function that hooks into "add_action('wp_footer', 'my_function')" it returns just fine but nowhere else in header and every other file it returns a blank array why!

Comment: I seem to be misunderstanding something. the post content is loaded way after the "wp_enqueque script" action has already ran it's course. so when "wp_enqueque script" is running the global variable is infact empty. only later you populate it with the selectors.

Comment: @UriChachick yeah i think now i understand why it works only in "wp_footer" in your opinion how is the best and easy way to populate an array with css from anywhere and print it via "wp_add_inline_style" this is all i need and seems to be impossible for me to make it work ?

Comment: I woudn't use "add_inline_style". that function is meant to attach those inline styles to an existing enququed wordpress style and it seems unnecessary. 
instead i'd have either create a function that print the global variable and hook it to a late hook like "wp_footer" or "wp_print_footer_scripts", or i'd have just print the global variable directly in the footer via theme files (footer.php most likely).
haven't tested it but i believe it'll work.

Comment: @UriChachick I agree with you but i'm limited by themeforest reviewers to print css only in "wp_head" via "wp_add_inline_style" or they will reject my project!

Comment: Let's try and adress it from a different direction - why do you create the custom css in the post content and not earlier?

Comment: @UriChachick because i'm using it on Elementor Widgets to generate custom and in Post Content to generate a "background-color" for image placeholders

Comment: the only thing I can think of is creating a function in functions.php and hook it to the "wp" hook (in which you can already get the $post object). in the function do "global $post" and then run over $post->content and send the selectors to your "cru_generate_custom_style" function and populate the global variable.

Comment: @UriChachick when i said "post content" i meant "content.php" file not the post content